# write into a text file issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this simple python code:

```
import facebook # pip install facebook-sdk
import json
import codecs
    ACCESS_TOKEN = ''
g = facebook.GraphAPI(ACCESS_TOKEN)

for i in range (0,2):

    f = open("samples"+str(i)+".txt", 'w')

    my_likes = [ like['id'] 
             for like in g.request('search', { 'q' : '&','type' : 'page', 'limit' : 5000 ,'offset' :i , 'locale' : 'ar_AR' })['data'] ]

    f.write( my_likes )
    f.close()
```

what I want to do is to store data exists on `my_likes` list into a text file. but a `write()` takes "no keyword arguments" error message appear to me. what am I doing wrong here?

**edit:** if I remove `indent=1` an error message appears: "expected a character buffer object"

Comment: What kind of output are you expecting? `write()` is meant to just write out a string - if you want it to be indented, you have to indent the string yourself.

Comment: What are you expecting `indent=1` to do?

Comment: `json.dump` accepts the `indent` argument, you probably meant to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I am doing wrong here?

The error message tells you what you are doing wrong; you are passing a keyword argument (`indent=1`) to `write()`, which shouldn't have any. As per [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), `write` only has one argument, the `string` to write. If you want to indent it in the file, add a tab (`'\t'`) to the start of each line in the string.

Comment: OK but if I remove indent=1 an error message appear : expected a character buffer object

Comment: Again, from the documentation, "To `write` something other than a string, it needs to be converted to a string first"

Comment: You're trying to write a list object to a file.  My guess is you maybe wanted to store JSON but I'm not sure.  IN that case use the `json` module.